# Resources (resx) don't work?

Tags: asp.net, embedded-resource

I have Resource files under App_GlobalResources.But now due to latest changes in project structure i need to move it to local project (Not to App_LocalResources).

I made resx files as

```
custom tool to : PublicResXFileCodeGenerator

custom tool namespace to: Resources

and build action: Embeded Resource
```

I want  `<telerik:RadButton runat="server"  ID="lblWeek" Text="<%$ManagementResources,ONE_WEEK %>"/>`

Which is not working

From code behind  on Page_init() it is working

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnsample.Text = SourceManagementResources.BUTTON_TEXT_INSTALL;
        }
```

But i don't want to do it from code behind .Some one please suggest how i can use it from my ascx control.

namespace of Resource file from designer is:

```
   namespace Resources {
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: "_is not working_" is way to few details.

Comment: I want to use from user control(ascx) page Text="<%$ Resources:SourceManagementResources, ONE_WEEK %>"

Comment: Any how this will not work since it is embedded resource any alternative so that it can work from ascx page